# App that launches prefpane app

Tags: preferences, app-launcher

I've been working on a .prefpane app and it's almost ready for the mac app store. The problem is that the product created from this app is a .prefpane file and not a .app file so as I see it I need to create an app that launches this .prefpane file so I was wondering how to do that?

Hope this makes sense!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [Mac App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/mac/resources/approval/guidelines.html) sections 2.15, 2.30, and probably some others, .prefpanes aren't allowed in the App Store.